# After effect script] how to create composition that setting use footage timecode

Tags: after-effects

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2r52.png)

I want a script(.jsx) that works the same as when I make a comp with a drag drop of Footage Source.
It's because i have to make a lot of footage source into each composition.

I can make a composition with the selected footage source.
But I can never get the start point time code for the footage source.
The difficult problem is that need cut start time code at 1:00:00:00
The time code that needs to be cut can change.

Someone help me.